# In sympy, is it possible for ratsimp to simplify also a non fraction element?

Tags: python, sympy

With this snippet:

```
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')
a,b,c=symbols('a b c')
ratsimp(a+1/b+1/c)
```

I get

```
a + (b + c)/(b*c)
```

while I would like to get

```
(a*b*c + b + c)/(b*c)
```

because I need the numerator of the fraction.

Is it possible?

Here it is a screenshot, I get `Out[1]` while I would like to get `Out[2]`:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `ratsimp` documentation says, its final step is to *reduce* the   rational function, that is to extract its polynomial part. Since this is not what you want, you should not use `ratsimp`. Instead, use `cancel` to get everything over common denominator, and if you want the numerator and denominator separately, also use `.as_numer_denom()`

```
>>> cancel(a+1/b+1/c)
(a*b*c + b + c)/(b*c)
>>> f, g = cancel(a+1/b+1/c).as_numer_denom()
>>> f
a*b*c + b + c
>>> g
b*c
```